# Is there a function to extract a value from a Singleton?

Tags: haskell, types, dependent-type, singleton-type

I'm developing a data type which requires an `SNat`, and would like to have the ability to give the user a `Nat` instead. Searching on Hoogle has yet to yield results.

That is, is there a function

```hs
f :: forall a (x :: a). Sing a x -> a
```

?

Comment: What about `fromSing`? https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-2.5.1/docs/Data-Singletons.html#v:fromSing

Comment: Thanks! That solves my problem. Althoug, do you know if there's ways of converting between the various Natural types? That is, the ones in GHC.Natural, Numeric.Natural, Data.Nat, Data.Natural, Data.Singletons.TypeLits, GHC.TypeLits and GHC.TypeNats

Comment: @schuelermine [That's what hoogle's for.](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=Natural%20-%3E%20Nat) If you have a different question, ask it elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `fromSing` from `singletons`